# What is this object on my exterior wall?

Tags: wiring, uk, tv-antenna

[image: black cylindrical object attached to exterior wall] This object is attached to the exterior wall of my three-year-old, estate built house. It sits immediately above the patio doors and internally, on the same wall, there is a black cable protruding from the wall whose connectors look similar to, but not the same as, coaxial connectors.

Is this a mounting point for a satellite dish? It seems to be oriented such that any dish would be facing the opposite direction to others that I can see around the estate. Does this matter? I've never had a satellite service before.

Comment: What does the inside look like if you remove the two screws? Post a well-lit and clear picture.

Comment: Can you take also a picture of the cable and connecters on the inside of the wall. Going on the picture only, it just looks like a standard electrical junction box, probably housing wiring for an outside light that the builders never bothered installing.

Answer (score 1):

My first guess would be, since it is over a door, that it is an outdoor lighting fixture. It would have a cable like Romex or somthing about the size of an extension cord. [image]

Second guess would be an external feed to the utility company.  Those look like little pucks and are usually about 2 inches in diameter.  It will have a small cable (the size of an Ethernet or phone cable) and they use them to read an internal meter without having to enter the house.  I couldn't easily find a photo.